# Difference between ${} and a regular variable

Tags: groovy

What would be the difference between

```
String test = "blah"
print("this is a test ${test} blah blah")
```

and

```
print("This is a test " + test + " blah blah")
```

Comment: [It is called string interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation). It is simply more readable.

Comment: The latter yields a `java.lang.String`, whereas the former yields an `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl`. It's mostly just syntactic sugar though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a string literal contains `${}`, Groovy constructs a **GString**.

Per its Javadoc, a GString:

> Represents a String which contains embedded values such as `"hello there ${user} how are you?"` which can be evaluated lazily. Advanced users can iterate over the text and values to perform special processing, such as for performing SQL operations, the values can be substituted for `?` and the actual value objects can be bound to a JDBC statement.

So the `"this is a test ${test} blah blah"` carries around its structure, which may be programatically examined. Whereas the `"This is a test " + test + " blah blah"` is an immutable String just as in Java.

Usually this doesn't have any effect on the programmer, but occasionally surprising things happen - see: [dynamically set the db in a sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267756/dynamically-set-the-db-in-a-sql-query)

Comment: Aah thanks. The SO question you linked was the problem I was having

Answer (score 0):

Actually every String that use *" "* is GString. And when you use *'    '* it means that you use java.lang.String. 
Unfortunately, String in Java is final class. So, groovy developers make workaround.

Comment: [Sure about that?](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5099807190286336). I observe that `"$x".getClass()` returns `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl` but `"abc".getClass()` returns `java.lang.String`.

Comment: Differs between versions perhaps?

Comment: @HuguesMoreau Groovy does a lot of magic. So it could convert GString to String.

Comment: @UladzislauKaminski Yes it does a lot of magic :) But it's not a black box, we can take a look inside. If I open `groovyConsole` with version 2.4.11, enter script `x=9; s1="9"; s2="$x"`, go to "Script → Inspect AST" menu, select phase "Conversion", and take a look at the result, I see `"9"` is transformed to `'9'`, and in the top left tree we can observe the difference between the statements: s1 involves a simple `String`, s2 a `GString`. Of course those are implementation details and might change across versions.

Comment: Hm no actually it's part of the [spec](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_double_quoted_string): "Double quoted strings are plain java.lang.String if there’s no interpolated expression, but are groovy.lang.GString instances if interpolation is present.". So if you add "potentially" in your first sentence, then it's a valid answer ;)