# groovy SQL rows() method

Tags: sql, grails, groovy

In my grails app a have next query:

```
def query = """select
                       u.id, u.birth_date, u.gender, uht.data
                    from
                       user_hra_test as uht
                       left join user as u on u.id = uht.user_id
                       left join client as c on c.id = u.client_id
                    where
                       c.id in (${clients*.id.join(',')}) and
                       uht.`date` between "${start.format("yyyy-MM-dd")}" and "${end.format("yyyy-MM-dd")}"
"""
```

When im executing it manually in my db i get 3 rows. But when i'm doing this:

```
def queryResult = db.rows(query)
```

the size of queryResult is 1. Where is a problem?

UPDADE. I manually deleted form the db the row wich was found, and now method returns nothing, but exequting sql in phpmyadmin returns 2 rows

Answer (score 1):

This most likely has to do with `Sql` / `GString` interaction. If you perform `def query = '''...'''.toString()` or a `def query = '''...''' as String` before the call to `db.rows(query)`it will most likely solve your problem. See [this](http://programmingitch.blogspot.ca/2010/10/be-careful-using-gstrings-for-sql.html) link for details and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621242/groovy-gstring-issues) link for a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
   def dataSource

   def nameMethod() {

       def sql = Sql.newInstance(dataSource)

       def query = def query = """select
                   u.id, u.birth_date, u.gender, uht.data
                from
                   user_hra_test as uht
                   left join user as u on u.id = uht.user_id
                   left join client as c on c.id = u.client_id
                where
                   c.id in (${clients*.id.join(',')}) and
                   uht.`date` between "${start.format("yyyy-MM-dd")}" and   "${end.format("yyyy-MM-dd")}"
               """

       sql.eachRow( query ) { 
           println it //Do whatever you need with each row
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, i don't know why, but it works when query looks like this:

```
select
                       u.id, u.birth_date, u.gender, uht.data
                    from
                       user_hra_test as uht
                       left join user as u on u.id = uht.user_id
                       left join client as c on c.id = u.client_id
                    where
                       c.id in ("""+clients*.id.join(',')+""") and
                       uht.`date` between "${start.format("yyyy-MM-dd")}" and "${end.format("yyyy-MM-dd")}"
```